# MsDeploy arguments not calling password variable

Tags: web, deployment, gitlab, cicd, webdeploy

Stuck on using msdeploy.
We got gitlab variables like deployuser and deploy password.
When command looks like this
msdeploy.exe -verb:'sync' -allowUntrusted -source:dirPath='C:\temp\publish' -dest:wmsvc='https://server:8172/msdeploy.axd?site=site_name',userName='plain_user_name','password='plain_password',authType='basic',IncludeAcls='False',dirPath='C:\inetpub\wwwroot\site_folder' then it's deploying with no errors
When I'm trying to use gitlab vars like $user, $pass etc i got error 401, unathorized.

So what I did:
seted global var in ci-cd like
$global_var = $pass_var
then in script
set-variable -name "PublisherPass" -value "$GLOBAL_VAR"
then called echo $GLOBAL_VAR and $PublisherPass and both of then  show's plain password like it suppost to be.
Then
source:dirPath='C:\temp\publish' -dest:wmsvc='https://server:8172/msdeploy.axd?site=site_name',userName='plain_user_name',password='$PublisherPass',authType='basic',IncludeAcls='False',dirPath='C:\inetpub\wwwroot\site_folder and it's show again 401
Localy on terminal, seting pass variable, echo $pass - show's password, then calling msdeploy with var $pass and 401)
also tried $pass$ , ${$pass} the same result (

I know i'm missing something, but don't know what exacly ))

Answer (score 0):

well I switched to ntlm and command now looks

- msdeploy.exe -verb:'sync' -allowUntrusted  -source:dirPath='src' -dest:wmsvc='https://c1d-vsr-cl-w1.dev.carmoney.ru:8172/msdeploy.axd?site=site',**userName=''**,**authType='NTLM'**,IncludeAcls='False',dirPath='path'

and now it works great

i believe it using runner service account (I thought I should create a local adm account for runner but no)
But this runner was on the local dev server, now I going to use another runner (also win runner) to deploy for other stages. Will see would this work or not)